# Reliable US yearly population and netmigration estimates by state from 1970 up to today

Tags: data-request, population-economics, migration

I am looking for US data on population and net migration by state and year from 1970 up to recent years (2015, 2016, 2017)?

Is there a reliable, clean and integrated/compatible source?

For 2010 to 2017 I found this [US Census State Population Totals and Components of Change: 2010-2017](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2017/demo/popest/state-total.html) website. Is there anything similar for previous periods?

Other sources I considered that are not adequate:

- Net Migration   Patterns for US Counties: only decennial
- [Census::CPS Historical Migration/Geographic Mobility Tables](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/geographic-mobility/historic.html): does not disaggregate by state

Answer (score 2):

[Census State to State Migration Flows](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/geographic-mobility/state-to-state-migration.html) are available from 2004 - 2016. Census's [State Intercensal Tables: 2000-2010](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/intercensal-2000-2010-state.html) has annual state population data over the 2000-2010 period. Combining this with Census's [State Population Totals and Components of Change: 2010-2017](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2017/demo/popest/state-total.html) gives population series for back to 2004.

Comment: tks. Tour 2000-2010 link is pointing to another dataset (2010-2017), which by the way also has relevant data on this. Please correct that.